# Is this categorical definition of homology correct and, furthermore, used to teach homology in some book?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I try to define abstract homology in the following way.
$\newcommand{\Ob}{\operatorname{Ob}}$
$\newcommand{\Arr}{\operatorname{Arr}}$
$\newcommand{\Com}{\operatorname{Com}}$
$\newcommand{\Fun}{\operatorname{Fun}}$
$\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$
$\newcommand{\cod}{\operatorname{cod}}$
$\newcommand{\img}{\operatorname{img}}$
$\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}$
$\newcommand{\imgs}{\operatorname{\underline{img}}}$
$\newcommand{\kers}{\operatorname{\underline{ker}}}$
$\newcommand{\cokers}{\operatorname{\underline{coker}}}$

> Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category. Consider the category $\Com \mathcal A$  whose objects are endomorphisms $d$ on objects $A$ with of $\mathcal A$ with $d^2 = 0$ and whose morphisms between obejcts $d$ and $d'$ of $\Com \mathcal A$ are given by arrows $f \colon A → A'$ in $\mathcal A$ (where $A = \dom d$, $A' = \dom d'$) such that $fd = d'f$.
>
> This can be viewed as a subcategory of the arrow category $\Arr \mathcal A$.
>
> Then kernel and image define functors $\Com \mathcal A → \Arr \mathcal A$. For any $d ∈ \Ob \Com \mathcal A$, since $d^2 = 0$, we have $\img d ≤ \ker d$, that is: there exist a uniqe morphism $η_d \colon \imgs d → \kers d$ such that $\img d = (\ker d) η_d$ (where $\imgs d = \dom (\img d)$ and $\kers d = \dom (\ker d)$).
>
> In turns out, this defines a natural transformation $η \colon \img → \ker$.
>   As taking domains is a functor $\Arr \mathcal A → \mathcal A$, this also defines a natural transformation $η \colon \imgs → \kers$ of functors $\Com \mathcal A → \mathcal A$.
>
> Since $\mathcal A$ is abelian, the functor category $\Fun (\Com \mathcal A, \mathcal A)$ is as well, and we may define 
>   $$h = \cokers η = \cod (\coker η),$$
>   yielding a functor
>   $$h \colon \Com \mathcal A → \mathcal A.$$

Now, I think of $\mathcal A$ as the category of $ℤ$-indexed sequences of abelian groups whose morphisms are $ℤ$-indexed sequences of homomorphisms of some degree (they may uniformly vary the index, so e.g. be homomorphisms $A_i → A_{i+1}$). I might possibly further refine $\Com \mathcal A$ to only contain endomorphisms $d$ of degree one as objects and homomorphisms $f$ of degree zero as arrows …

My questions now are

1. Have I successfully described homology as the functor $h$ in this way?
2. If so, is there any book that does homological algebra based on this or a similar definition in a purely categorical way?

I would especially like to see homology *not* defined on chain complexes, but first defined on endomorphisms $d$, and only then specified to chain complexes. (Or is this completely useless?)

Comment: So far I found it mentioned only briefly in Mac Lane, "Homology" and some remarks on compatibility in Spanier, "Algebraic Topology".

Answer (score 8):

This is exactly how [Michael Barr](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/) develops homology theory in section 2.4 of his book *[Acyclic Models](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/acycmod.pdf#section.2.4)*.

Comment: That’s neat! Thanks for the answer. I won’t accept this, though, as Michael Barr doesn’t do homological algebra in a *purely* categorical way in this book (that is, without falling back to the category of modules over some ring for convenience in proving theorems).

Comment: A reference for a purely categorical approach is Theo Buehler's survey *[Exact categories](https://arxiv.or/abs/0811.1480)*. You can probably combine Barr's discussion of differential objects in additive categories with Buehler's to get what you want.